# Being notified when Python security updates are made

Tags: python

I maintain a few Python-based web apps. I need to be notified immediately when new Python releases are made, especially micro level releases that fix security issues, so I could update my sites to use the new version.

Is there any way to be automatically notified? I looked at `python-announce-list` but it has notifications for a myriad of open-source projects that I'm not interested in.

Comment: Recommending a move to serverfault, this has nothing to do with programming. Personally I'd recommend subscribing to securityfocus or something similar.

Comment: Agreed and voted, awaiting fifth voter.